# Why click event gets prevented with multiple mouse events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a bar chart with these events:

1. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` that I use to calculate the total time a cursor was in an `SVG`
2. `mouseover`, `mousemove`, `mouseleave` for the tooltip which is created for each rectangle.

I have 3 radio buttons that I use to display different `SVG` (so on `change` I remove the current `SVG` and create a new one). Now the issue is that I think there is a clash between these events. Sometimes I cannot click on the radio button, but everything else works fine. Why is the click event gets prevented? I have multiple `SVG`in my page and I apply the same thing. Could that be the issue?
A link to my working code: [enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCi0PM7jfwTlNfJe?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

I have tried using `d3.event.stopPropagation();`  but I think I am placing it in the wrong location. Here is where I am placing it:

```
  let mouseover = function() {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 1)
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
  }
  let mousemove = function(d) {
    tooltip
      .html(d.key + " speak  " + d.data[d.key] +"%")
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+70) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
  }
  let mouseleave = function(d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0)

  }
```

so the problem of the click button being stuck only happens if I hover over the rectangles, the click works smoothly if I don't hover.

Comment: Are you sure it's the event handling causing trouble? To me it looks more like a problem with the data loading via `d3.csv()` where, every now and then, a *500 Internal Server Error* shows up.

Comment: My assumption that it's the event handler causing the issue, because when I commented out the mouse movement the problem( i.e the _500 Internal Error_ and the event handling issue)